# How to query external webservice in saltstack state and assing value to varriable

Tags: salt-stack

I wish to create a `saltstack` state and use data from external API in it. The problem is that the URL of the API has variable data (ID) in it. For instance `http://some.url.com/cmdbid/{host.id}`. The `{host.id}` is different for each host and is present in salt grains. Is it possible to query data from external API over HTTP in `saltstack` state and use variables in the URL?

In `saltstack` state I have tried to use `'http.query'` and `'cmd.run'`. I cat get `saltstate` to do its job when hard coding `host.id` in the state, but I cannot do that, because each host has a unique ID.

```
{% set hostid = salt['grains.get'](id) %}
{% set url = salt['http.query']('http://some.service.com/id/{{ hostid }}') %}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of a state.
Remember that you do need to match on a status code or text because Salt needs to report if the state was executed successfully.

```
query_api:
  http.query:
    - name: http://example.com/restapi/{{ grains['id'] }}
    - status: 200
```